# How to dimension a heat pipe + radiator for passive cooling of the RPi 4 B?

Tags: pi-4, cooling

I'd like to cool a [Raspberry Pi 4 Modell B](https://www.rasppishop.de/Raspberry-Pi-4-Modell-B-4GB-SDRAM) with passive cooling only. To get the heat away from the chip I'd like to use a heat pipe and radiator to distribute the heat. Something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32367165474.html). My problem is, that I don't know how to dimension the heat pipe + radiator properly for RPi4 not overclocked and run under industrial conditions, means a temperature range between -40 to +85 °C. Does someone have experience and/or a recommendation?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should not buy from the vendor you've linked to - [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32367165474.html).

Why? Because they provide no spec sheet.

Repeat the following mantra 3 times each morning when you wake up:

> ***NO SPEC SHEET - NO SALE!***

You need thermal resistance and airflow curves which are typically derived empirically by the manufacturer. You could do this yourself if you had a laboratory and proper instrumentation, but if you had that equipment I doubt you'd be asking this question here.

This is crap - do not buy it. If you're still interested in heat pipes as a solution, you might peruse [this answer for some more details & ideas.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/112905/83790)

Comment: Totally agree on "You definitely should not buy from the vendor you've linked to - this. Why? Because they provide no spec sheet.". It was just an example ;)

Comment: "You could do this yourself if you had a laboratory and proper instrumentation, but if you had that equipment I doubt you'd be asking this question here." Yes, that's right. I was looking for practical experiences or hints w.r.t. simulation (something like [simscale thermal analysis](https://www.simscale.com/product/thermal-analysis/) but simpler.

Comment: @thinwybk: I've not used `simscale`, so I can't comment on it specifically, but it can't be any more difficult than [e-mag modeling of antenna structures](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/simulia/products/cst-studio-suite/), so it probably increases insights. I think the key thing to keep in mind re heat pipes is their primary function is to move heat from one place to another - not so much to dissipate it. They're fascinating devices. Oh - don't forget that RPi has a *closed-loop Thermal Management System*. This TMS adjusts your system performance based on its temperature.